# (SMTP in a Website) What is the better practice: continuous connection or single-use connection?

Tags: asp.net-core, web-applications, smtp, consistency

It seems that most SMTP servers have limitations. Some may limit connection duration while others may limit connection frequency. When the limitation is reached, the SMTP service may not be available. I wonder whether I should disconnect immediately or keep connection after one email is sent, because in my scenerio, there may be lots of emails sent in a short period, and may also be no email sent in a long period.

Besides, can you give me some advices on how to deal with those emails that were failed to sent? How should I store them and when should I resend them? How do I keep consistency even though the application stops or the server is down?

Comment: I'm not going to use Microsoft Graph or SendGrid, as they are far too complicated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.